# MongoDB Linq nested Child Collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

lets say I have this collection:

```
{
   "_id":"5d6d7333111acd18a0d0b383",
   "Bundle":{
      "_id":"5cf031c4abe00cbf4540f0b4",
      "Variations":[
         {
            "_id":"5cf031c37ea1d40960fd111f",
            "Code":"45A",
            "Label":"Modelo A",
            "Description":"",
            "VariationType":"A",
            "Summary":null,
            "Assets":[
               {
                  "Asset":"ST_MT_1040_N",
                  "Price":"48000",
                  "CanBeExcluded":false
               },
               {
                  "Asset":"CP_IN_1015_A",
                  "Price":"84000",
                  "CanBeExcluded":false
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In c# I would like to list the collections that have a specific Asset code.

```
ex: Bundle.Variations[0].Assets.Asset
```

Variations is IEnumerable but ALLWAYS has only one object, so I get the .First()

Some tries that I did:

**FIRST TRY:**

```
    var builder = Builders<ClientProject>.Filter;
    var test1 = builder.Eq(!partnerId.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? "PartnerId" : "ClientId", clientId ?? partnerId)
                    & builder.Gte(xx=> (int)xx.Status, 7)
                    & !builder.Eq(xx=> (int)xx.Status, 90)
                    & builder.Eq(xx=> (int)xx.ProjectType, 0)
                    & builder.Gte(xx=> xx.StartedWithPoOn, from)
                    & builder.Lte(xx=> xx.StartedWithPoOn, to)
                    & builder.ElemMatch(yy=> yy.Bundle.Variations.First().Assets, assetCode);
```

**SECOND TRY:**

```
    var test2 = _coll.AsQueryable()
                        .Where(xx=> (int)xx.Status >= 7
                                        && (int)xx.Status != 90
                                        && (int)xx.ProjectType == 0
                                        && xx.StartedWithPoOn >= from
                                        && xx.StartedWithPoOn <= to
                                        && xx.Bundle.Variations.First().Assets.Any(yy=> yy.Asset == assetCode))
                        .ToList();
```

Both ways did not work at all!!

Would have a LINQ way to return this or I would have to query Mongo diretcly using Aggreggtions with BsonDocuments? how would be? would have to use UnWind? projections?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this working example. if you've stored Status, ProjectType as strings in the db, you will need `BsonRepresenation` attributes on the class props. also need to change Variations from `IEnumerable` to `List`.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class ClientProject
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartedWithPoOn { get; set; }
        public ObjectId PartnerId { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public int Status { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public int ProjectType { get; set; }

        public Bundle Bundle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bundle
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public List<Variations> Variations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variations
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string VariationType { get; set; }
        public Assets[] Assets { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Assets
    {
        public string Asset { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeExcluded { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coll = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
                            .GetDatabase("test")
                            .GetCollection<ClientProject>("ClientProject");

            var result = coll.AsQueryable()
                             .Where(xx =>
                                    xx.Status >= 7 &&
                                    xx.PartnerId != null &&
                                    xx.ProjectType == 0 &&
                                    xx.StartedWithPoOn >= new DateTime(2019, 09, 25) &&
                                    xx.StartedWithPoOn <= new DateTime(2019, 09, 29) &&
                                    xx.Bundle.Variations[0].Assets.Any(yy => yy.Asset == "ST_MT_1040_N"))
                             .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first did not work because my Variations is IEnumerable, so I change to Variations.ToList()[0], compiled, but did not run, exception "The expression tree is not supported: {document}{Bundle}{Variations}.ToList().get_Item(0).Assets". Maybe will work if my object was a List<Variations> so I would not need the ToList... Looking this Linq, I think I will try a raw BsonDocumment  with a pure mongo query. I guess will be faster and clean. Thanks any way Ryan! cheers

Comment: Just for testing, I changed to List my object, even doing that, throws an exception ""Unsupported filter: IIF(False, ({document}{PartnerId} == null), ((((((({document}{ClientId} == \"5caf91cd800fc20002cad0fb\") AndAlso (Convert({document}{Status}, Int32) >= 7)) AndAlso (Convert({document}{Status}, Int32) != 90)) AndAlso (Convert({document}{ProjectType}, Int32) == 0)) AndAlso ({document}{StartedWithPoOn} >= 01/01/2019 00:00:00)) AndAlso ({document}{StartedWithPoOn} <= 12/31/2019 23:59:59)) AndAlso Any({Bundle.Variations.0.Assets}.Where(({document}{Asset} == \"MT_MT_1066_A\"))))).""

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR i updated the answer with a full working example.